# IS-A relationship with only single sub entity

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012, relational-theory

Hi I'm trying to design a database for a dictionary. The words has several fields like meaning, an example, and maybe a picture. but the words that are 'verbs' has three more special fields that the rest does not. So is this a Is-A relation ship? but I tried this: 
I made a table for words with all sharing fields and a type field, and a table for verbs. these two tables has a one to one relation. the verb table just has the special fields and the foreign key. so if a user wants to only search for a verb he/she needs to search from all words that has the "type == verb". is this a good idea?
Please help me how to design this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've created a subtype which is a good normalization technique. Sounds like it meets your requirements here... so you should be fine. For a full fledged (e.g. OED) database you might find too many unique elements to create such a design though.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the answer, by the way I'm always doubtful about designing database, is there any book you can recommend me for mastering system analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not create another table for verbs because join operations on big tables (especially multiple ones in the same query) may be expensive. I would create one table, with the shared AND the non-shared fields, AND add another column "isverb", set it to 1 for verbs and 0 for non-verbs. You could also later on add "isadjective" etc.

In this case it just makes sense to do:

```
SELECT * FROM words where isverb = 1
```

rather than:

```
SELECT * 
FROM words w 
INNER JOIN verbs v ON w.type = v.id 
WHERE w.type = 2
```

The application is a dictionary. So it's write once, read a zillion times and so I don't personally see a need for a complicated database design. You essentially just need very fast reads which you can achieve without joins to multiple tables

Comment: Have you measured how expensive joins are?  I thought it was one of the core concepts of any RDBMS and therefore one of the best optimized operations in the IT world.

Comment: And what about the other word types and the type-specific columns?

Comment: What about them? I don't follow. As I mentioned in my answer, I would put all columns in one table, and add isverb, isadjective, iswhatever columns to distinguish between the word types

Comment: And in this case you'll get a (very) sparse table.  This may be good or bad, but in most cases I'm aware of it's not really a desirable design.

Comment: If you add all your reasoning to your answer and remove 'join operations are expensive', you are eligible for an upvote from me - even if I'm not sure it will be faster this way than that way (this is true in both directions, performance tests are always welcome).

Comment: Nice approach but this will add lots of null data, So you are saying that this way is still better than Join costs, right?